# How to install dual boot Kubuntu and Remix OS

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu

I currently have a PC with **Kubuntu** installed by itself and i wanted to dual boot **Remix OS** since i need Android apps with a Android-like environment.

Comment: You need unallocated space on your disk for new partition for Remix OS. If you don't have it, you can cut some current partition or add new disk to your PC. Next, install Remix OS to new partition and finally update your  GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

As per these instructions: https://forum.xda-developers.com/remix/remix-os/how-to-install-remix-os-alongside-t3352890 you will need to create a new partition large enough to house Remix OS, install Remix OS onto that partition, and then update grub to be able to see Remix